# Generate Floorplan

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To my game in Unity I want to generate a random floorplan, but I don't know how. I thought about the flood fill algorithm but because this then should generate rooms in this blueprint I thought about generating x shapes and then mash them together. My friend told me there was an algorithm for that but I cant find the name of it, maybe you know it or how would you approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many courses on this online. [One such class](https://www.udemy.com/share/103NGo3@SqArDYI6VwW74DUV70TOwhGZySHApsGEhpS0X3zo0Fqiyf1glXNc2JSdpOnSlypO/) that I took covers generating mazes.

In that class, they cover:

1. Basic Crawler Algorithms (Including the Drunken Crawl algorithm)
2. Wilsons Algorithm
3. Prims Algorithm
4. Depth First Search Algorithm
5. Recursive Generation Algorithms

If you are willing to do the research yourself, you can take these algorithm names and create it yourself. The course I linked, while helpful, isn't worth the cost it asks for and I recommend that you only pay for it if you're stuck.